# Group arrays by id and check

Tags: php, arrays

Managed to improve code and now I have results which I expected, but i have another problem. I need to find if in #id array is service_id '833'.

```
foreach ($r as $dump_r => $r_rows)
{
    echo $dump_r;
    foreach ($r_rows as $row)
    {
        echo $row['service_id'];
    }   
}
```

My results looks like:

```
#113540
833
6295
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54200662/edit) your question and show us an example of expected result with a given input?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your results to be grouped you should investigate the GROUP BY option from SQL.

Your question is also pretty unclear "check if where is " makes no sense to me.

The foreach is really simple to use, using your example you can:

```
foreach( $result as $row){
  $r[] = ['id'=>$row['id'],'service_id'=>$row['service_id']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your initial $result from the SQL-Statement to be grouped you should use the Group By in your statement at $sql.

If you want to group it after the selection of your data then you have to loop with a foreach through the data.

Or maybe a simple sort() function can help you out.

For example you could use

```
$service_ids = array(69, 10, 85); // here you have to input your ids you want to sort/order
sort($service_ids );

$clength = count($service_ids );
for($x = 0; $x < $clength; $x++) {
    echo $service_ids [$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This gives you the ouput

- 10
- 69
- 85